# Display current year starting on August 1 - PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

I need a PHP function that displays the previous year until August 1, at which point it should display the current year.

For example:

- today is May 12, 2011, so this should echo "2010"
- when it's August 1, 2011 this should echo "2011"
- ...continue to echo "2011" until August 1, 2012
- on August 1, 2012, it should echo "2012"
- etc.

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Agree with @Mark Baker. This is a relatively easy question to answer with just a little bit of research.

Comment: So basically show a fiscal year with August 1 as its starting date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
$year = date('Y') - 1;
$month = date('n');

if($month >= 8) $year++;

echo $year;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/qOx1TO95

Comment: I think you are one off in your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$august = strtotime('1 August');
if(time() < $august) {
  echo date('Y') - 1;
}else{
  echo date('Y');
}
```

Comment: @Emil...   does this mean august of every year? this doesnt look right

Comment: It does. strtotime should default to the current year. But I agree more with your solution - didn't think straight when I chose strtotime over date :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function year($timestamp) {
    if(date('m', $timestamp) < 8) {
        return (date('Y', $timestamp) - 1);
    }
    return (date('Y', $timestamp));
}
```